# Length of unique list elements by group in a dataframe

Tags: r

I wish to calculate the length of unique `list` elements by a group in a column Name in `data frame`. My input `data frame`:

```
NameList = list(c("Sam", "Gemma", "Alison", "Tom"),c("Oliver", "Alison"),c("Tom", "Alison", "Harry"),c("Vin", "Harry"), c("Jason", "Sam", "Harry"),c("Anton", "Harry"),c("Harry"),c("Vin", "Jack"))

df <- data.frame(Name = c('Alison','Alison','Alison','Harry','Harry','Harry','Harry','Jack'), NameList = sapply(NameList, paste0, collapse = ','))
```

I would like to calculate unique length of list elements by group`df$name` as below:

```
Name    unique_Num_Name
Alison   6
Harry    5
Jack     2
```

I know how to get a length of unique list of elements  `length(unique(unlist(df$NameList)))`. But, for my data frame, I was not successful to get by a group. So, I would appreciate any guide or help.

Comment: Please `dput` and `str` your data (`df`) and share the outputs here. It's not clear what the type of the `NameList` column is.

Comment: @Abdou I added `dput` of `NameList`. It is a list.

Comment: `tapply` will do it. `with(df, tapply(NameList, Name, FUN = function(x) length(unique(unlist(x)))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages from the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
separate_rows(df, NameList, sep = ",") %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarise(uniq_names = n_distinct(NameList))
```

The result is:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    Name uniq_names
  <fctr>      <int>
1 Alison          6
2  Harry          5
3   Jack          2
```

**Input data:**

```
NameList = list(c("Sam", "Gemma", "Alison", "Tom"),c("Oliver", "Alison"),c("Tom", "Alison", "Harry"),c("Vin", "Harry"),
                c("Jason", "Sam", "Harry"),c("Anton", "Harry"),c("Harry"),c("Vin", "Jack"))

df <- data.frame(Name = c('Alison','Alison','Alison','Harry','Harry','Harry','Harry','Jack'),
                 NameList = sapply(NameList, paste0, collapse = ','))
```

Comment: I had to modify some of my code. Now, your script is working very well. Thank you for your help. I am upvoting and accepting your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Split to groups defined by `name` and use the `length-unique-unlist` combination for every group:

```
lapply(split(dat, dat$Name), function(x) {
  length(unique(unlist(x$NameList)))
})
```

**Update:**
As Rich Scriven suggested in comments, the `tapply` is better choice here:

```
with(dat, 
  tapply(NameList, Name, FUN=function(x) 
    length(unique(unlist(x)))
  )
)
```

Sample data:

```
structure(
  list(
    Name = structure(
      c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
        3L),
      .Label = c("Alison", "Harry", "Jack"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    NameList = structure(list(
      c("Sam", "Gemma", "Alison", "Tom"),
      c("Oliver", "Alison"),
      c("Tom", "Alison", "Harry"),
      c("Vin",
        "Harry"),
      c("Jason", "Sam", "Harry"),
      c("Anton", "Harry"),
      "Harry",
      c("Vin", "Jack")
    ), class = "AsIs")
  ),
  .Names = c("Name",
             "NameList"),
  row.names = c(NA,-8L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

Comment: `tapply()` might be a better choice here. `with(df, tapply(NameList, Name, FUN=function(x) length(unique(unlist(x)))))`

Comment: @RichScriven yes, it is. Thanks.